# What is this small brown pill shaped thing?

Tags: identification

These objects recently appeared in my house. They have a hard but very thin brown outer shell with indented circles around the cylindrical direction. The shell is only loosely attached to the underneath can be peeled off to reveal a smooth cream-coloured surface of the same shape. If that it squeezed, it bursts and liquid comes out, creamy both in colour and consistency. I live in the United Kingdom. What could this be?[image]

Comment: Have you got plants inside the house? Do you live on the ground floor? And do these 'objects' move? Did you collect them up just to photograph them, and if so, how/where were they distributed when you found them  (as in near a window or door or skirting board or whatever...)?

Comment: We do have plants, but two rooms away from where they were found, which was in the corner of the room near the front door on the ground floor. They were bunched together more or less as pictured, about 15 in total. I've seen no movement at all.

Comment: They look like [cabbage maggot pupae](https://organicgardeningnewsandinfo.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/cabbage-maggot-pupae.gif)

Comment: Amazing, thank you. What could be a likely source, and should we be terrified?

Comment: They can be pupae of other insects as well. Where did you find them, near a trash can or something like that?

Comment: They also look like housefly pupae.

Comment: Not near to anything very much, just in the corner of the room by the front door.

Comment: Sorry for closing this so quicky, it’s just not about gardening. I hope the comments helped nevertheless.

Comment: I am the weirdo around here, I think anything that has to do with insects has everything to do with gardening.  This could be one of two things; rat poop or a chrysalis/pupal form of a moth?  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Actias_luna_pupa_sjh_enhanced.JPG/103px-Actias_luna_pupa_sjh_enhanced.JPG

Comment: http://www.wildlife-removal.com/ratvsmousepoop.html

Comment: by your description of surgery, sounds like chrysalis of a pupa.  Good for you to not be so squeamish!  If these things are on the floor, look up to see what is above you.  Rat poop would be uniform throughout.  And make sure you wash your hands really well!

Comment: @stormy As an owner of pets rats for many years, I can say without hesitation that those brown things are not remotely related to rats.